# Neovim Right Side Shift Keymap

Tags: neovim

I wanted to have right side shift keymap in my neovim lua configuration. But nothing from the neovim wiki, no online information about right shift detection. Tried `<S-Right>` but this would be shift + right arrow. Chatgpt says neovim doesn't recognise left/right shift :(

Comment: Detecting the right shift key in nvim can't be possible due to the limitations of your terminal emulator and nvim's handling of key codes. The `<S-Right>` notation you tried is for `Shift + Right arrow`, but nvim does not recognize the distinction between left and right shift keys directly. you should consider custom scripting or any other key combination.